# how to pass parameters to tortoiseproc.exe via file?

Tags: file, command-line, parameters, tortoisesvn

I am programmatically generating a command to be submitted to cmd.exe using Runtime.getRuntime.exec() from java.

The command is tortoiseproc ignore command of the form

```
tortoiseproc /command:ignore /path:file1*file2*file3*...................filen
```

As you can see, the path parameter takes a number of files and problem occurs when this string exceeds a certain length approx. 8197 characters as documented in microsoft KB for cmd.exe.

The workaround there says that modify the program so that it accepts the parameters from a file rather than from the commandline string. Does anybody know how to pass parameters to tortoiseproc.exe via file?

Answer (score 2):

you can pass a file in utf16 format, with each file listed on a separate line.

Pass the path to that file with `/pathfile:"path/to/file.txt"`

Comment: How do I create a UTF16 encoded file? I tried using PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(tempFile), Charset.forName("UTF-16"))); but tortoiseproc returned an error. further ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's not possible. However, *in this specific case*, it doesn't matter: you can split the file list into multiple smaller ones, and run the tortoiseproc multiple times. Example:

```
tortoiseproc /command:ignore /path:file1*file2*file3*file4
tortoiseproc /command:ignore /path:file5*file6*file7*file8
```

and so on, up to file *n*.

Comment: I had thought of this option but then it was going to be inefficient so I chose to use svn command line tool to set the ignore property which accepts the ignore patterns from a file.  svn propset ignore -F tmpfile . where tmpfile represents a file with ignore patterns separated by newline characters. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and this is my solution for that:

```
using (var s = File.Create("D:\\p3.tmp"))
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(s, new UnicodeEncoding(false, false)))
    {
        sw.Write(@"D:\SourceCode\Utils\ProductProvider.cs" + '\n');
        sw.Write(@"D:\SourceCode\Utils\BillingProvider.cs"+ '\n');
    }
}
```

after file is created I use

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit /pathfile:"D:\p3.tmp" /logmsg:"test log message" /deletepathfile
```