# Save text file with UTF-16 encoding without Byte Order Mark (BOM) in C#?

Tags: c#, tortoisesvn, utf-16, byte-order-mark, endianness

---

I've read similar posts on this and they don't answer my question.

Similar post I found is :
[how to pass parameters to tortoiseproc.exe via file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694423/how-to-pass-parameters-to-tortoiseproc-exe-via-file)

---

but the problem is unresolved and stuck on creation of file with UTF-16 encoding without BOM.

I'm trying to automate commits for my project using tortoisesvn command

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit /pathfile:"D:\p3.tmp" /logmsg:"test log message" /deletepathfile
```

where **"D:\p3.tmp"** file contains list of files that must be commited.

**This file shuld be with UTF-16 encoding without BOM.**

**C# Code** that I use to create a file:

```
string line = @"D:\SourceCode\ProductProvider.cs";           
    using (var s = File.Create("D:\\p3.tmp"))
    {
     using (var sw = new StreamWriter(s, new UTF32Encoding()))
     {
         sw.WriteLine(line);
     }
    }
```

Comment: Hello from the future! You ask about UTF-16, but your code example generates UTF-32. Not sure which you intended. The accepted answer generates UTF-16.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to use a non default [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984ebfcy.aspx) of the [UnicodeEncoding class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding.aspx) to create an UTF16 encoding without a BOM;

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(s, new UnicodeEncoding(false, false)))
{
    sw.WriteLine(line);
}
```

The first `false` sets little endian encoding, you can set it to true for big endian. The second `false` disables the BOM.